# Spotify Client on iMac G5 running Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, apt, package-management, mac, powerpc

I tried installing Spotify today on my iMac G5, using [this](https://www.spotify.com/us/download/linux/) as a guide. I was able to install the key, but was unable to access the repository, no matter what I tried. When I ran `sudo apt-get update`, I got an error that looks like this.

```
    W: Failed to fetch http://repository.spotify.com/dists/stable/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'non-free/binary-powerpc/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
```

Why am I not able to find the packages? Is it because PowerPCs are not supported? Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Spotify repository does not have PowerPC packages. It only has sources for amd64 (64-bit) and i386 (32-bit) processors.

Wine supports PowerPC, and you can use the winetricks program to install the Windows version of Spotify. Another workaround would be to install Flash Player and use the Spotify Web Player.

https://www.winehq.org/

https://play.spotify.com/